# How to use JSONP GET request with the OpenWeatherAPI?

Tags: jquery, json, callback, jsonp

I am trying to use the [OpenWeatherAPI](http://openweathermap.org/wiki/API/2.0/JSON_API) to perform get JSONP data using a JQuery `get` request. I have structured my query like this:

```
function getWeather(callback) {
    var weather = 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=13.3428&lon=-6.2661&cnt=10&jsoncallback=?';
    jQuery.getJSON(weather, callback);
}

// get data:
getWeather(function(data){
    console.log('weather data received');
});
```

I get the following error message:

> SyntaxError: invalid label

However, the data is being returned as I can click on it in Firebug and it gives me the expected results. I am performing this all on the client-side so perhaps I have a basic mistake on my JSONP request. Searching on this topic also suggested that the returned data may be in JSON form and not JSONP, but I am unsure of what the difference is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the built in JSONP functionality to handle the callback for you. Just use $.ajax instead, as so:

```
function getWeather(callback) {
    var weather = 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=13.3428&lon=-6.26612&cnt=10';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: weather,
      success: callback
    });
}

// get data:
getWeather(function (data) {
    console.log('weather data received');
    console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].description);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wCjW3/1/

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the api say that you should use `callback` instead of `jsoncallback` as parameter in the url.

[Descriped in the table here](http://openweathermap.org/wiki/API/2.0/JSON_API)

> callback - functionName for JSONP calback. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Follwing code works for me:

```
$.getJSON('http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=13.3428&lon=-6.2661&cnt=10&callback=?', function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I don't quite understand how this handles the cross-domain issues (although it does work fine as far as I can tell).

Comment: You aren't allowed to do ajax requests on other domains, but you can include and execute scripts from others domains (like CDN for jquery).  JSONP uses this as a workaround to the same origin policy. JSONP returns a script that contains a function call with the data as parameter. The function is localy defined in your code.