# Not able to get data from openweatherapi

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, openweathermap

I am trying to create a simple Weather APP and I am using the jquery Ajax method to retrieve the data from openweathermap.  I am using the following method to get the data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submitWeather').click(function(){
let city = $("#city").val();
if(city != ''){
  //Get the AJAX request.
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1",
    type: "GET",
    //jsonpadded.
    dataType: "jsonp",
    //the callback for success.
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}else {
  $("#error").html('Field cannot be empty');
}
 });
 });
```

The problem I am having is that it is not getting the data showing it in the console.log.  This is the error I am getting in the console.log

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1&callback=jQuery31106677768465103353_1512307813960&_=1512307813961 net::ERR_ABORTED
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ app.js:6
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: Just putting that URL in a browser shows that the API is returning a "401 Invalid API Key Response".  You should make sure you're using a valid API Key for starters.

Comment: I am a numpty. I was using the wrong key.  Thanks for that Robert ;)

Comment: I thought he didn't put his own APPID in public, it was just a place holder appid for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dataType of ajax request is "json" not "jsonp"

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

UPDATE:

openweathermap supports "JSONP" but you are using it wrongly here is an example of how to use it with $.ajax to call a named method

```
function callback(data){
    console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp : "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "callback"
        });
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  Openweather appears to support JSONP.  See the selected answer here, as well as the examples the author provided. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567402/how-to-use-jsonp-get-request-with-the-openweatherapi